# test command is showing in green on zsh terminal

Tags: zsh

In zsh, `test` command is showing in green

This only happens when there is a valid binary exists for the command.

I am just curious why it is showing green for `test` command furthermore it is not giving any error on hitting the `test` command

[image]

```
echo $ZSH_THEME
powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k

zsh --version
zsh 5.8 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: This by itself is not directly done by zsh. My guess is that you have installed some package (*oh-my-zsh* or *zsh-syntax-highlighting* perhaps), which colorizes words based on whether or not they are executables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small extension (possibly part of the powerlevel10k theme) that colorizes the text on the command line. One thing it does is do progressive path lookup on the name of the command you are typing. If no command is found, the text is red. Once a valid command *is* found, the color becomes green.

This is independent of whether the command, when executed, succeeds or fails. `test` with no arguments fails, as noted by the `1x` in the following prompt.

Comment: sorry @chepner Then it should show in red, why it is showing in green. Am i missing something from your answer?

Comment: The command `test` *exists*; that's what the coloring the command line itself indicates.

Comment: oh! `test` command checks file types and compares values.

Comment: This has nothing to do with what the command does when executed. It's the *shell* checking for the existence of a command by that name as you type it. `t`, `te`, and `tes` should all be red while you are typing; once you type the final `t`, it will turn green. `test` and `clear` are commands; `hello` is not.

Comment: oh yes i got it! i was saying that i didn't know `test` command exists in unix like system.